# spark dynamically groupBy multiple column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to spark and I have a requirement of grouping multiple column for a dataframe which looks like below schema.

```
root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Traffic Volume Count Location Address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Street: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date of Count: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Passing Vehicle Volume: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Vehicle Volume By Each Direction of Traffic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
```

And i need to group two column say `Street` and `Total Passing Vehicle Volume` for which the below code looks like:

```
trafficDf.groupBy("Street","Total Passing Vehicle Volume").count().orderBy("Street").show(100)
```

But the problem is on how many column I need to perform grouping I dont know in upfront this is something a runtime info which I'll be getting as a json and from json I have to extract the column on which I need to perform grouping.
I know I can convert my `dataframe` to table by `createOrReplaceTempView` where I can run a SQL query on top of that. But I'm wondering there must be some way without writing SQL.

What I know `df.select()` which can i take `expr()` like:

```
df.select(expr("Id as new_Id, Street as new_Street")).show()
```

If the same thing I'm passing in `groupBy()` I'm getting error:

```
var dynamic_condition="Street, Total Passing Vehicle Volume" // this will be created from json where i'll get column names by looping through runtime info
trafficDf.groupBy(expr(dynamic_condition)).count().show()
```

Error:

```
mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 6)

== SQL ==
Street, Total Passing Vehicle Volume
```

I'm doing something wrong I have checked documentation of `groupBY()` also I think it can't take `expr()` as argument or may be. Any help will be appriciated

Note: I know it can be possible by writing a SQL query on top of dataframe but I'm trying with some other way.

Comment: You can dot this: `val grpCols = dynamic_condition.split(",").map(c => col(s"`$c`"))`
then `df.groupBy(grpCols: _*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example above you are passing the list of columns as `String`, you need to pass it as a `List[String]`

From the API documentation

```
def groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*): RelationalGroupedDataset
```

A sample code snippet is shown below

```
def dynamicGroup(df: DataFrame, cols: List[String] ): DataFrame = {
  df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)
}
```

You can then call it as below

```
val listOfStrings =  List("A", "B", "C")
val result = dynamicGroup(df, listOfStrings)
```